# How to find the value of this product of tensors?

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

I was asked to find the value of $A_{lm}x^lx^m$ under the condition that the tensor $A_{lm}$ is skew-symmetric. I´ve tried using coordinate transformation for $A_{lm}$, $x^l$ and $x^m$, then applying the defintion of the skew-symmetric tensor to the result, but I cannot progress further this. Is there something that I´m missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression is zero, because it is both symmetric and skew-symmetric in the indices $\ell$ and $m$. Namely, one can write $$A_{\ell m}x^\ell x^m \stackrel{(1)}{=} A_{m\ell}x^mx^\ell \stackrel{(2)}{=} -A_{\ell m}x^mx^\ell \stackrel{(3)}{=} -A_{\ell m}x^\ell x^m,$$and the conclusion follows. In (1), one renames the dummy indices $m \leftrightarrow \ell$. In (2), we use skew-symmetry of $A$. In (3), we just switch the order $x^mx^\ell = x^\ell x^m$ (because multiplication of real numbers is commutative).

For some weird reason people may have a really hard time understanding (1). It is for the same reason one can write things such as $$\sum_{i=1}^n b_i = \sum_{j=1}^n b_j = \sum_{k=1}^n b_k, \qquad \int_0^1 f(x)\,{\rm d}x = \int_0^1f(t)\,{\rm d}t  = \int_0^1 f(s)\,{\rm d}s, \qquad \mbox{etc.}$$